# Export Table CSV format using R without overwrite using Sys.Date()

Tags: r, csv, export

Good night guys, does anyone know how to help me export this table without overwriting? I would like to put the system date in my code, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to follow an example here, but it didn't work for me.

write.table (dataset, file = "C: //Users//Acer//OneDrive//ALLPARTS//texto.csv")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer

write.table(dataset, file = paste0("C:/Users/Acer/OneDrive/ALLPARTS/VIN_", format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d"), ".csv"))

Answer (score 0):

You could use `paste` in combination with `System.time()` to construct your file name:

```r
file = paste0("C:/Users/Acer/OneDrive/ALLPARTS/texto_", Sys.time(), ".csv")
file
#> [1] "C:/Users/Acer/OneDrive/ALLPARTS/texto_2020-04-04 23:43:02.csv"
```